# How can i remove specifics and repeat words from Python List?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, reorderlist, reorderable-list

Hello i hope yall good im trying to deleted some items and words from a List.

```
ListA = ['', 'dulce_renaca', 'pastelerialuly', 'cons.bakery', 'kukkichile', 'panaderiasanjoaquin', 'ceciliabolocco\nVerified', '', 'coasthealthyfood', 'bajozeroalimentos', 'dulce_renaca', 'kukkichile']
```

I want to eliminate all the empty items like " " and the repeated words like "dulce_renaca". and also remove or split the ones that contains the word "\nVerified.

Expect Result:

```
ListB = ['dulce_renaca', 'pastelerialuly', 'cons.bakery', 'kukkichile', 'panaderiasanjoaquin', 'coasthealthyfood', 'bajozeroalimentos']
```

Please help me and teach me how to do it.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: `list(set(word.replace("\nVerified", "") for word in ListA if word))`

Comment: A simple way could be, use remove method to remove "" and then use set to remove duplicate values.

Comment: filtered = list(set(filter(lambda word: len(word.strip()) > 0 and word.find("\n") == -1, ListA)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ListA = ['', 'dulce_renaca', 'pastelerialuly', 'cons.bakery', 'kukkichile', 'panaderiasanjoaquin',
         'ceciliabolocco\nVerified', '', 'coasthealthyfood', 'bajozeroalimentos',
         'dulce_renaca', 'kukkichile']

v = [list(n for n in x.split("\n")) if "\n" in x else x for x in list(set(filter(None,ListA)))]
d = []
for b in v:
    fun = lambda x: d.extend(x) if len(x) < min([len(v) for v in list(set(filter(None,ListA)))]) else d.append(x)
    fun(b)
```

Filter is to filter out the none values and set is used to remove the duplicates.
Then we use for and lambda function to flatten out the list.

```
d
Out[101]: 
['dulce_renaca',
 'coasthealthyfood',
 'bajozeroalimentos',
 'cons.bakery',
 'kukkichile',
 'pastelerialuly',
 'panaderiasanjoaquin',
 'ceciliabolocco',
 'Verified']
```

The Output...The Above code and output if you want to split the value that had "\n" in it...

If you want to remove that value

```
ListA = ['', 'dulce_renaca', 'pastelerialuly', 'cons.bakery', 'kukkichile', 'panaderiasanjoaquin',
         'ceciliabolocco\nVerified', '', 'coasthealthyfood', 'bajozeroalimentos',
         'dulce_renaca', 'kukkichile']

v = [x  for x in list(set(filter(None,ListA))) if "\n" not in x]
```

The above code will work

```
v
Out[106]: 
['dulce_renaca',
 'coasthealthyfood',
 'bajozeroalimentos',
 'cons.bakery',
 'kukkichile',
 'pastelerialuly',
 'panaderiasanjoaquin']
```

The above is the output....

Comment: thank you very much for your time and help! 
Hope you have a great day!